# Icons not showing

Tags: applications, desktop, icons, desktop-environment, storage

I am using elementary os 6.1. When my storage became full then most of icons disappeared. Now I have remove some stuff and freed some space but my icons still not showing. Here are some screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by copying hicolor directory from /usr/share/icons/ to ~/.local/share/icons/